# Google Delegates on Calendar Framework / EventKit

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, eventkit

I have always run with the assumption that Google delegates can be viewed by iCal and the calendar.app, but are not visible to us developers through the calendar framework, or EventKit.

Has this changed?

Comment: delegates can be added since iOS5 if that's what you mean

Comment: Did you went through product's support?

Answer (score 4):

I have the problem too.  Calendars show up twice.  Deselect the delegates.  A little later everything disappears.

Apparently its a problem on google's side.  They claim to be "working on it" [Check discussion](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/AWJSWllOt9Y/discussion)

I found the google thread on another apple forum page devoted to the same problem:[Here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4512975?start=0&tstart=0)