# How do you access all CalDAV calendars/events on OSX?

Tags: cocoa, eventkit, calendar-store

I want to access all the calendars that a user can see in iCal on OS X. I know about EventKit and CalendarStore. However, it seems that both of those frameworks omit CalDAV delegate calendars (which are visible in iCal). Others have noticed this as well:

http://openradar.appspot.com/7077307

[Google Delegates on Calendar Framework / EventKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936115/google-delegates-on-calendar-framework-eventkit)

So if EventKit and CalendarStore don't do this, how does one proceed?